# Python ImportError after reinstallation of nautilus

Tags: python, install-from-source, python-2.7

I have a problem with python on my Ubuntu 12.10.

Firstly the problem arose when I was trying to reinstall nautilus because of some troubles with it. I used `apt-get --reinstall install nautilus*`. The installation was successful, but nautilus was unable to run because of python error:

```
grigory@grigory:/usr/local$ nautilus
Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
Initializing nautilus-image-converter extension
Initializing nautilus-dropbox 0.7.1
Initializing nautilus-open-terminal extension
Initializing nautilus-ideviceinfo extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

I searched through google and stackoverflow and found out that the problem could be caused by some problems with python versions: with [cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301735/importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat-with-cx-freeze), [something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297892/ubuntu-importerror-cannot-import-name-maxrepeat#comment23331452_16297892) and others.
Namely, the problem is connected with updating from python 2.7.3 to newer versions.

Recently I was stupid enough to install python 2.7.5 manually from sources. And now I have 2 pythons installed: 2.7.3 in `/usr/bin/` and python 2.7.5 in `/usr/local/bin/`. I suppose the problem is somehow connected with this fact.

The links provided above deal with python `virtualenv`, but in my case there is no virtualenv, I guess. Although I am a kind of newbie to Ubuntu and python, so I can mistake.

What can I do to solve the issue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: With `apt-get --reinstall install nautilus*` you have installed many extra useless packages. `nautilus*` does not mean "anything that _starts with_ nautilus", but "anything _containing_ nautilu".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, the problem is brought by the fact that you have two Python 2.7 installed in two different locations.

Specifically, it seems that Python 2.7.**3** (from Ubuntu) is using modules from Python 2.7.**5** (locally installed). Why this is happening is hard to tell without more information.

What I would do is removing Python 2.7.5: if you did not install anything else in `/usr/local`, then you can remove its content.

Comment: Will I have problems with Ubuntu applications using Python if I remove locally installed version? Will Ubuntu understand automatically that now it should use Python from the global folder? I am asking because now I run locally installed 2.7.5 by just typing `python` in Terminal.

Comment: @strelga: it's quite the contrary: you may have problems if you keep incompatible locally installed packages without proper isolation. Ubuntu applications will work well if you give them the Python version provided by Ubuntu.

Comment: @strelga: the fact that your default `python` is 2.7.5 is exactly your problem. You are seeing it because `/usr/local/bin` is in your `$PATH`. If you remove Python from `/usr/local/bin`, the one in `/usr/bin` will be used.

Comment: I removed Python from local and Nautilus now is back, thank you. One more question: there is `python2.7` folder in `usr/local/lib/` directory. Should I delete it too (does anybody besides locally installed Python use it)?

Comment: @strelga: yes, better remove it.